# Сравнение List<Uri> и поиск количества общих url по условию - как лучше сделать с linq?

Tags: c#, list, url, linq

Имеется два `List<Uri> urls_1` и `List<Uri> urls_2`

Возникла необходимость сравнивать url при условии:

сравнивать абсолютные урлы, не учитывая регистр и незначащие параметры, убрать utm-метки

Как можно сделать такое сравнение?
Как можно изначально сделать url с указанными параметрами, чтобы после просто url сравнивать через Intersect используя ling.

И как можно найти количество общих url?

Comment: [Intersect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Intersect__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) может принимать IEqualityComparer в котором можно описать что именно и как сравнивать

Comment: Видел такое дело, но как его применить к моей задаче так и не понял

Comment: просто вызываешь `urls_1.Intersect(urls_2, new UriEqualityComparer())` где UriEqualityComparer - это твой класс, в котором ты определяешь как сравнивать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: `urls_1.Intersect(urls_2, new UriEqualityComparer())`

UriEqualityComparer создан по данному ответу:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671208/how-to-do-a-custom-compare-for-every-item-in-a-intersect-of-two-collections